# Suspend Hibernate Issues, 18.04, Macbook Pro Late 2011 13"

Tags: suspend, encryption, hibernate, macbook

This is my second MBP 2011 13". The first one died in automobile accident and at the time had it running with a SSD and 16.04 flawlessly. I recently bought another simply because I love the design and wen't with 18.04 because of a longer lifetime. I currently installed with encryption via the installer and the only function not working is both suspend and hibernate. I have tried changing to the latest version of Mint and has the same issue. I have tried non encrypted installation with 17GB SWAP file as well as partition to match the 16GB RAM. It would originally just power off when I close the lid and not enter suspend or hibernate state and now it tries to resume and starts the RAM error beep code when I reopen the lid. Please Help Me!

Comment: I have managed to hibernate successfully by installing hibernate via command line and running through command line as well. I noticed it uses S2disk. Does normal hibernate not?